# Unable to Start Kapacitor Server in Linux Ubuntu

Tags: influxdb, opentsdb, kapacitor

Error :

**Using configuration at: kapacitor.conf
[run] 2016/06/07 18:36:23 E! init logging: open /var/log/kapacitor/kapacitor.log: permission denied
run: init logging: open /var/log/kapacitor/kapacitor.log: permission denied**

tried doing it from the documentation given in the site :
https://docs.influxdata.com/kapacitor/v0.13/introduction/getting_started/

Comment: The `permission denied` error indicates the `kapacitord` process may not have the right permissions. What version of Ubuntu are you running?

Comment: I'm using ubuntu 16.04 LTS in VirtualBox

Comment: Does kapacitor start if you use systemd? e.g. `sudo systemctl start kapacitor.service`.

Answer (score 0):

solved the issue i had to set permissions to the folders that ive saved        these kapacitor files, now im able to access them and all had to do is istall influxdb, telegraf and kapacitor and see that influx db and telegraf is running